# tell an array to hold instances of an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct, instance

lets say I have

```
struct Two {var names: String }
```

then I create two instances of this struct

```
var one = Two(names: "one")
var two = Two(names: "two")
```

Would I be able to create an array that specifically holds struct instances, something like?

```
 var options:Two = [[one],[two]]
```

If not, what would be the advisable path to complete this logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. The type you're looking for is `[[Two]]`, which is a 2D array of `Two`, or an array of arrays of Twos. Usage:

```
struct Two {
    var names: String
}

var one = Two(names: "one")
var two = Two(names: "two")

var options: [[Two]] = [[one],[two]]
```